# Website available even with no NGINX processes running

Tags: nginx

I have pulled into my web server so it has the latest code from my repo, i try to restart nginx - this doesnt do anything.

So I try the command
sudo nginx -s stop, and get the response that its failed because there is no such file or directory "run/nginx.pid" failed.

Trying to run the command ps aux | grep nginx gives me the response: unsupported option (BSD syntax) -- it actually comes out as ps aux > grep nginx in the digital ocean console.

Basically it seems that even though there are apparently no nginx processes running (although the command to check isnt working) my website is still running and using the old code, is there a way for me to check more definitively on the running processes?

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo netstat -plunt` to check if there's any nginx process running. See if there's anything running on port `80` or `443` and then look at the corresponding program name. You might have another server running possibly `apache` since it ships by default with most distributions which may be why `nginx` failed to start.

Another reason why it won't start might be due to faulty config. Go to `/etc/nginx/` and double check that it's correct. You can also run `sudo nginx -t` to ensure that the config syntax is correct.

Alternatively, just check your `nginx` access log to see if it's actually serving any requests. You can also check the error log to see why it might fail to start. These resides in `/var/log/nginx` by default or check your `nginx.conf` for any custom path to logs.